# Eclipse Source Control Plugin for Team Foundation Server 2008

Tags: tfs

My team has been adopting TFS 2008 for our team development and we are continuously and steadily learning to work with it. However, we got a project which has to be done in Java and would like the source control to be done in TFS 2008. We are therefore looking for an Eclipse plugin that can allow us achieve this.

I have found on the Internet a plugin called ***Teamprise*** but unfortunately it was taken over by Microsoft and I don't seem to see where I can get the older plugin which works with TFS 2008.

Is there anyone over there who can recommend an eclipse plugin that works or still works with TFS 2008? I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=af1f5168-c0f7-47c6-be7a-2a83a6c02e57) supports all versions of TFS (2005 through 2010).  It's just that the version of Team Explorer Everywhere is branded as 2010.

> System Requirements
>
> ```
> * Supported Operating Systems: Apple Mac OS X; HP-UX; IBM AIX; Linux; Solaris; Unix; Windows 7; Windows Vista; Windows XP Service Pack 2
> ```
>
> Requires Visual Studio 2005 Team
>   Foundation Server or **Visual Studio 2008**
>    Team Foundation Server or Visual
>   Studio Team Foundation Server 2010.

Comment: Just to confirm that Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 does indeed support Team Foundation Server 2005, 2008 and 2010.  (I'm one of the dev's on the team - formerly from Teamprise)

Answer (score 0):

The Teamprise Eclipse plug in for TFS gets a new name "Eaglestone".

Check following link:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/rfennell/archive/2010/03/08/the-teamprise-eclipse-plug-in-for-tfs-gets-a-new-name.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=519&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Where have you been ;) Its been called Team Explorer Everywhere since launch in April. It was indeed called Eaglestone in the time between Microsofts aquisition and its release in conjunction with the Visual Studio 2010 launch.